# scroll event is being triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling a function when the scroll is 800px away from the bottom. It calls that function multiple times but I want to call that function only once and then load some data and again when I go to 800px form bottom then again it should call that function only once. That function name is `load_data()`.

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 
    800 ) {
    // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
    var id = $('#load_more_button').data('id');
    $('#load_more_button').html('<b>Loading...</b>');
    if (id >= 1) {
     load_data(id, _token); 
    }       
  }
});
```

Comment: you want to call function on first scroll and then 800 from bottom??

Comment: how can I get only first scroll ?

Comment: only at 800px from bottom?

Comment: @RV I've solved it. Thank you very much for your effort

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the scroll event is getting triggered multiple times right in a row. So your function is getting called when window.scrollTop() is 800 from the bottom, then 799 from the bottom, 798 from the bottom before the code in your if is actually triggered.

Try re-setting window.scrollTop(value) so that it can never get past 800 from the bottom instead. That way your function is only called once.

Comment: Thanks for your attention!
I've tried this way already but once its scrolls are stored in browser and even scrolltop is reset those scrolls are being called

Comment: To add to this, you might try a [throttling function](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf) to prevent the call from happening too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a 'if' condition which will run whenever the 
        $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 
    800 
This means that whenever the value of

```
    $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()
```

falls above the value of

```
    $(document).height() - 800
```

the function will always get called. Try using '===' instead of '>' so that the loop will be triggered only once for a specific value.

You can also try and use a control. Lets say; introduce

```
    var hasRun = 0; //increment this value once the condition
    // $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 800 
    //is true.
```

decrement the value of var hasRun whenever

```
    $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - 800
```

is true.
Please try this.

```
     $(window).scroll(function(event) {
var hasRun = 0;
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 
800 ) {
hasRun = hasRun + 1;
}
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $(document).height() - 
800 ) {
hasRun = 0;
}
if(hasRun <= 0){
// ajax call get data from server and append to the div
var id = $('#load_more_button').data('id');
$('#load_more_button').html('<b>Loading...</b>');
if (id >= 1) {
load_data(id, _token);  
}       
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sam for your effort.
Okay let me try this .

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is how you want.

```
function load_data(id = "", _token) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "load_data",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id,
            _token: _token
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#load_more').remove();
            $('.post_data').append(data);
            scrollFlag = false;
        }
    });
}
console.log(id);
var flag = false;
var scrollFlag = false;

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(document).height() - 400;
    if (!scrollFlag) {
        scrollFlag = true;
        if ((scroll > height || !flag)) {
            // ajax call get data from server and append to the div
            var id = $('#load_more_button').data('id');
            $('#load_more_button').html('<b>Loading...</b>');
            if (id >= 1) {
                load_data(id, _token);
            }
            flag = true;
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qu1eon2d/

Comment: Thank you for your response.
what if more data is left to load?

Comment: didnt get you. can you please explain it?

Comment: I mean when I scroll to 800 then it calls that "load_data()" function once and each time it loads eight(8) portfolios, but if there is a situation that more data is to load. Then what should be the code?

Comment: how you are getting that data still remain to load??

Comment: I'm using ajax request to fetch data.This function `load_data()` make an ajax request to fetch data

Comment: no. im saying is there anything that says that data is remains to load?

Comment: yes there is a button having text "scroll down to load more data" until entire data is not fetched . If whole data is fetched then it show this text " no more data"

Comment: here is my load_data function
`function load_data(id="", _token)
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"load_data",
     method:"POST",
     data:{id:id, _token:_token},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#load_more').remove();
      $('.post_data').append(data);
     }
    })
   }`

Comment: I am very grateful to you.

Comment: This seems very tough to understand though. can you please add new question or add more information about exceptions or problems you are having?

Comment: if you just want to load data on when scroll reach 800px bottom. please remove flag  variable checking

Comment: If I remove flag variable from if then it doesn't load data all the time

Comment: how much data you have?

Comment: 32 portfolios are in database and each time 8 are loaded

Comment: will you please tell me why "scrollFlag" is using ?

Comment: to call scroll only once that also needs to remove

Comment: will you remove button load more or change something at the last call of data??

Comment: i mean what is changing when data is finished to load? so i can update my logic

Comment: Load more button has "id" which is changing after each ajax call.

Comment: it will be 0 after finish??

Comment: I'm checking this id in laravel controller before fetching data from SQL

Comment: it will 1 after finish and remove and then "no more data" button appears

Comment: Just Edited Answer. try now.

Comment: where to place the scrollFlag variable?

Comment: again it is calling load_data() function multiple times

Comment: when we scrolls down and crosses 800 from bottom then browser stores the mouseWheel event and stores how many time mouse was scrolled after 800 crossed and then calls "load_data()" function multiple times

Comment: Updated something. try

Comment: if this also call multiple times put scrollFlag=false; into your ajax success

Comment: not worked in both scenarios. 
I'm very thankful to you for helping me but I don't know what's the problem happening :(

Comment: i meant remove  scrollFlag=false; from scroll function just only in ajax success

Comment: same as earlier it's calling only once

Comment: keep it that way im just looking into it

Comment: Just Updated My Answer. If you want to try.